# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an error with Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE.

I don't know where the error is coming from.
Autowire annotation is suppose to create the bean for me. What other annotation I'm I missing ?

**Here the code**

Controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest/accounts")
public class AccountController {

private AccountService accountService;

public AccountController() {}
@Autowired
public AccountController(AccountService accountService) {
    this.accountService = accountService;
}
```

Repository class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {
@Autowired
private AccountRepo accountRepo;

@Autowired
private BlogRepo blogRepo;

@Override
public Account findAccount(Long id) {
    return accountRepo.findAccount(id);
}
```

**Here the error**

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw
>   exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet
>   threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'accountController' defined in file
>   [/Users/Mayor/Documents/workspace/PascalWebStore/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/PascalWeb/WEB-INF/classes/com/sci/pascal/rest/mvc/AccountController.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [com.sci.pascal.core.services.AccountService]: : No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.sci.pascal.core.services.AccountService]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.sci.pascal.core.services.AccountService]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.sci.pascal.core.services.AccountService]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) note The full stack trace of
>   the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.21 logs.

Any help are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: "No qualifying bean of type [com.sci.pascal.core.services.AccountService]" - so you need to mark AccountService as a Bean as it is not a Bean at present. Also you have to add in an XML file <context:component-scan base-package="name of package that AccountService class resides" />.

Comment: AccountService is an interface, i implemented in the AccountServiceImplemetation class. I also used the service annotation on this class so that spring will recognize it as a bean. but i still get this error - No qualifying bean of type [com.sci.pascal.core.services.AccountService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Set this property in your `spring-servlet.xml` file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="base package name" />
```

Comment: I did that already. <context:component-scan base-package="com.sci.pascal.rest.mvc" />

Comment: and I also have about 10 controller classes, do I have to declare each bean on an xml before I can use it?

Comment: No it is not necessary to write bean in XML you can use @controller annotation to tell compiler that this is controller class

Comment: yes I have a controller annotation on the class already. but still doesn't work. i also @autowire the constructor of this controller class like this
      
       public AccountController(AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
       }

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone i found the error spring didn't find the configuration file 
i included

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml</param-value>
```

in my web.xml file.